# Installing flask; python script still cannot import

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I have tried every command line installation possible in an attempt to install flask. I have followed the instructions from http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/installation/

After `sudo easy_install virtualenv`:

```
Searching for virtualenv
Best match: virtualenv 1.11.6
Adding virtualenv 1.11.6 to easy-install.pth file
Installing virtualenv script to /usr/local/bin
Installing virtualenv-2.7 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Processing dependencies for virtualenv
Finished processing dependencies for virtualenv
```

after `pip-install flask`:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): flask in ./python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Werkzeug>=0.7 in ./python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2>=2.4 in ./python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): itsdangerous>=0.21 in ./python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): markupsafe in ./python2.7/dist-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask)
Cleaning up...
```

However after  `. venv/bin/activate`:

```
bash: venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

I do know how to navigate around the terminal and create directories. I am uncertain how to process this command and/or activate virtualenv. I cannot find this directory or perhaps the sudo/pip commands were intended for a directory not defaulted on my drive?

I try and run a python script using flask, and of course:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testingflask.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Here is the script:
testingflask.py

```
from flask import flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I have tried `apt-get install python-flask` as well

Comment: Activate your venv *first*, then use pip. Or explicitly use the `bin/pip` in the virtual env directory. You installed Flask in globally, but by default a virtual env ignores the global packages.

Answer (score 1):

Did you did the

```
$ mkdir myproject
$ cd myproject
$ virtualenv venv
```

step? (Apparently not)

In any case you should do the `pip install Flask` after activating the virutualenv. Else it get installed in you base python install.

Also take care, python is case sensitive:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Comment: Remember you need to activate the virtual environment with `. venv/bin/activate`. This has to be done each time you open a new shell.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `virtualenv venv` ? I mean do you have a `venv` folder in your project? 
I guess you missed that step!

1. `$ sudo easy_install virtualenv` or `sudo easy_install virtualenv`
2. `$ mkdir myproject`
3. `$ cd myproject`
4. `virtualenv venv`

I you follow those steps you should have a `venv` directory in `myproject` and the command `$ . venv/bin/activate` will work

Answer (score 0):

### One more thing to try

- know your python path where site-packages are stored
- download the [flask module](http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/F/Flask/Flask-0.10.1.tar.gz) and extract it
- copy the extracted folder and paste it into your python packages directory(mostly **site-  packages/dist-packages** `for me :/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`) [remember ***root only can do this***]
- open your python shell
- and check `"import flask"`

#### know the location of your library files:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.path
Out[2]: 
['',
 '/usr/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

Comment: I do have flask install in this path above, but whenever I move around and create a virualenv venv and then try to install flask via pip install flask I receive the following error `bash: /home/phillipk/rampup/sql/venv/bin/easy_install: /home/phillipsk/rampup/webapp/sql/venv/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` and here are my contents of that path `activate  activate.csh  activate.fish  activate_this.py  easy_install  easy_install-2.7  pip  pip2  pip2.7  python  python2  python2.7
(venv)kup@kuprevicius:~/rampup/sql/venv/bin$ python`

Comment: I think you can copy the `flask` modules and paste inside the `venv` lib packages directory and try it to run `import flask` in `python` shell